# Does Handler execute Runnable's simultaneously

Tags: android

A non-UI thread in my Android application contains a Handler object, and I add implementations of Runnable to this Handler using the post() method.

From reading the API, it seems that Handler uses a queue. Does this mean that if I post() 2 Runnables to the queue, that the second one will only start executing on completion of the first Runnable's run method?

Just wanted to confirm this as I am seeing some multi-threading issues in my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As per I understand your question)

As per the [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), Handler using a MessageQueue, The 2nd runnable execution starts after completion of the first,

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

Answer (score 1):

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable
> objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler
> instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's
> message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to
> the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it
> -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables
> to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the
> message queue.

> There are two main uses for a Handler:
> -1- to schedule messages and runnables to be
> executed as some point in the future; and
> -2- to enqueue an action to be performed on a
> different thread than your own.

Quote from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
Relate to your question, it is `YES`, the 2nd one will run after the 1st Runnable done.